# Yii2 dektrium user new action

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I use dektrium yii2-user in advanced template. I want to add new action in SettingsController.

What I've done:

Override SettingsController. Created /frontend/user/SettingsController.php

```
namespace frontend\controllers\user;

use dektrium\user\controllers\SettingsController as BaseSettingsController;

class SettingsController extends BaseSettingsController
{

    public function actionMyview()
    {
        $this->render('myview');
    }
}
```

Created new view /frontend/views/user/settings/view/myview.php
And changed /common/main.php in components section

```
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@dektrium/user/views' => '@frontend/views/user'
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

But it doesn't work. When I go to mysite.com/user/settings/myview I see blank page without errors.
Also I don't know how to override behaviours, so I added access rule for myview directly in /vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/controllers/SettingsController.php

How can I do that things right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
'user' => [
    'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
    //...
    'controllerMap' => [
        'settings' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\controllers\user\SettingsController',
            'layout' => '@app/views/layouts/main'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I got it! you forgot this is `return`

```
public function actionMyview()
{
    return $this->render('myview');
}
```

Comment: Show a url that you request

Comment: I set layout and it doesn't work too. My url mysite.com/user/settings/myview

Comment: is your debug set to true in frontend/web/index.php ?

Comment: I test on basic template Yii2

Comment: Debug is true, no errors show and no errors in log file.

Comment: check `init function` in SettingsController `public function init(){ parent::init(); die('ok');}`

Comment: You forgot `return`!

Comment: Thanks! I spent a lot of time to research and it's so stupid thing that I forgot. But strange why there was not errors, I have centos, nginx and php-fpm.

Comment: Action Controller is executed, but there is no output render, so the blank page was